# What's the origin of chess?

Tags: history

I have heard numerous times that stated that India was the inventors of the original chess. I have also heard that the origin was in the Middle East. Sometimes I heard that the origin was in Arabia. As I have heard many things I wanted to know the right answer. If there is no right answer, please give the closest guess.

Comment: Everything should be in wikipedia.

Comment: This question is too broad for a focused Q&A site like Chess Stack Exchange. The Wikipedia article mentioned in the [history tag wiki](http://chess.stackexchange.com/tags/history/info) is a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comment that the question is too broad.

However, in the spirit of helpfulness, these pages:

https://www.chess.com/blog/jim_ostler/history-of-chess12

http://www.tradgames.org.uk/games/Chess.htm

http://www.chessmaniac.com/the-etymology-of-chess/

https://www.quora.com/Who-invented-chess-and-how

http://www.chessdryad.com/articles/wcc/transcribed/origin.htm

may be useful in addition to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

agree..broad ?..info for fun. There are 13 different claims to the origin of chess. No proof. Earliest documentation--600 A.D. Chaturanga - 4 sided game in what is now India. In this authors opinion chess was originally a 2 player game changed to a 4 player game then back to a 2 sided game. Trivia-the one peice that has not changed apperance or move pattern-knight..last major rule changes....Q & O-O..France 1400s.   Source "A Short History of Chess" by Henry A. Davidson m.d.1949

Answer (score 0):

There is no definite answer, but the most likely place was the Middle East.